# HighCharts. How to align yAxis title and yAxis labels to right in one line?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Help please to config "Highcharts". I can not align the title and labels on the right side on the one line. Labels are cropped if they have been recalculated in formatter.

[image]

yAxis option config:

```js
chart: {
   spacingLeft: 0
},
yAxis: {
   offset: 12,
   title: {
      rotation: 0,
      align: 'high',
      y: -21,
      textAlign: 'right',
      x: 0,
      margin: 0,
      offset: 0,
      text: 'ttl'
   },
   labels: {
      x: 0,
      align: 'right',
      formatter: function(e) {
         return e.value * 333;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Nazar Ugrinovsky, Your options seem to be enough to achieve the intended result.: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/85cdjmL0/ Could you describe what exactly is wrong?

Comment: Forgot added that labels are recalculated in **formatter** function.

Comment: Still the result seems to be correct: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3t652b4q/

Comment: Take a closer look, the first character is cut off

Comment: If the title is null, the chart on the left appears indented
(https://snag.gy/YzmSjl.jpg)

Comment: Set spacingLeft to get rid of the indentation and see the labels clipping
```chart: {
   spacingLeft: 0
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this problem is caused by your custom `offset` value: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c9uLkp3n/

Comment: But I need a space between labels and chart. Please tell me how to set it up

Comment: To create the space use: `spacingLeft` property: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9fkvwru8/

Comment: This is the indent of the entire chart along with the labels, and I need between the labels and the chart. https://snag.gy/bLhnSJ.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `title.x` and `labels.x` properties to set the space. The `x` value is included in chart size calculations:

```
yAxis: {
    title: {
        rotation: 0,
        align: 'high',
        y: -21,
        textAlign: 'right',
        x: -10,
        margin: 0,
        offset: 0,
        text: 'ttl'
    },
    labels: {
        x: -10,
        align: 'right',
        formatter: function(e) {
            return e.value * 333;
        }
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/67bv3nts/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.labels.x

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.title.x